# Scrollspy - Page messing up when linking nav bar page to outside url

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, nav, scrollspy

I need help with JQuery, I believe this may be obvious solution but I don't know how to go about it. In regards to the nav bar on my scroller page, I want one of the links on the nav bar to go an external page (not to a section in the page). It will do this, but it messes up the scrolling page, (backgrounds move to the wrong section etc). I believe I have to change the refElement but I'm unsure.. Please help :( thanks

```
/*=========================================================================
        Navbar ScrollSpy
    =========================================================================*/
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop(),
        nav_height = $('#navbar').outerHeight();

    $('.navbar li a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this),
            refElement = $(currLink.attr('href'));
        if( refElement.size() > 0 ){
            if ( ( refElement.position().top - nav_height ) <= scrollPos ) {
                $('.navbar li').removeClass('active');
                currLink.closest('li').addClass('active');
            }else{
                currLink.removeClass('active');
            }
        }
    });


});


//Initialize smoothscroll plugin
smoothScroll.init({
    updateURL: false
});
```

-----------------------------HTML--------------------------------

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class=container>
    <div class=navbar-header>
        <button aria-expanded=false class="collapsed navbar-toggle" data-target=#nav-collapse data-toggle=collapse type=button><span class=sr-only>Toggle navigation</span> <span class=icon-bar></span> <span class=icon-bar></span> <span class=icon-bar></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id=nav-collapse>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class=active><a href=#intro data-scroll>Home</a>
                <li><a href=#features-3 data-scroll>Marine</a>
                    <li><a href=#features-4 data-scroll>Industrial</a>
                        <li><a href=#contact data-scroll>Contact</a>
                            <li><a href="https://www.example.com" data-target>Careers</a></ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

did some more digging around and found this snippet which works. thanks

```
/**
 * Scroll Spy via Bootstrap
 */
$('body').scrollspy({target: "#nav_wrapper", offset:50});

/**
 * Scroll Spy meet WordPress menu.
 */
// Only fire when not on the homepage
if (window.location.pathname !== "/") {
    // Selector for top nav a elements
    $('#top_main_nav a').each( function() {
        if (this.hash.indexOf('#') === 0) {
            // Alert this to an absolute link (pointing to the correct section on the hompage)
            this.href = "/" + this.hash;
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Initiate Awesome Smooth Scrolling based on a.href
 */
$('a.smooth-scroll, #top_main_nav a').click( function() {
    target = $(this).attr('href');
    offset = $(target).offset();
    $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop : offset.top }, 700);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```